# Conjugacy classes for automorphism group of simple lie type group

Tags: group-theory

I have two questions. Thanks for any comments.

Suppose $S$ is a simpe group of Lie type in characteristic $p$. Also suppose that $G=Aut(S)$.

1) Is there any reference for conjugacy class of element $g$ of $G$? (GLS has some results for the case $p=2$) In particular when $g$ is a field automorphism, is there any result?

2) Is there a field automorphism of order $p$, when $p$ is the characteristic of $S$ ?